# saving a file in php without saving in a folder in yii php

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Am saving a file as a `long blob` in `php` by first saving it in a folder then to a db, the problem is that the server has write permissions so i would like to save it directly

**This is what i have tried (This works perfectly):**

```
 if(isset($_POST['image'])){

        $id = 0;

        $image = $_POST['image'];
         $tmp_image = date('YmdHisu').'.jpg';

        file_put_contents($tmp_image, base64_decode($image));

         $sql = "INSERT INTO fingerprint(template)
            VALUES ('".addslashes(file_get_contents($tmp_image))."')";

                try
                    {
                               $connection=Yii::app()->db; 
                                $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);

                                $rowCount=$command->execute(); // execute the non-query SQL


                    echo "saved successifully";
                    unlink($tmp_image);

                    }
                    catch(Exception $ex)
                    {
                        echo 'Query failed' , $ex->getMessage();
                        unlink($tmp_image);
                    }


            }
```

How can i save this in a `blob field` in `mysql` without first having to save it in a folder then saving to db

Comment: If `$_POST['image']` really contains the content of the file (I doubt it), then simply `addslashes($_POST['image'])`

Comment: The $_POST['image'] contains a string of the file encoded in base 64 format, thats why am decoding it above. The above works perfectly

Comment: What version of yii are you using?

Comment: Am using yii version 1

Comment: You should upload it with the yii standard way: Creating a model for uploading your file.

Comment: Am using php logic way, the string comes from android to yii so i cant use the cuploaded get instance which i believe is the yii standard way.

Comment: Anyway using the php logic way is wrong in a Framework because you're going outside the MVC structure. You can access the physical file you're uploading with $_FILES php global variable. Reefer to this S.O. question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584908/yii-saving-an-image-from-files-but-without-using-models

Comment: Then how do you suggest i use the mvc way and yet the file is an encoded string passed as a post request

Comment: The code is in the controller, the model is used to save it in the db, i believe its the mvc way but using php logic in this

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you've sent the file via Android using POST method to your server running Yii1.

First of all the physical file is contained in the $_FILES variable and in the $_POST variable, as you said, contains a string of the file encoded in base 64 format (i write this for a clear answer).
[$_FILE DOCUMENTATION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

Now this is how you can try to upload the file with the standard MVC yii way using yii code:

It's true that you're uploading your file from an external device but Yii came in your help with [CUploadedFile](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile#getInstance-detail) Class:

> Call getInstance to retrieve the instance of an uploaded file, and then use saveAs to save it on the server. You may also query other information about the file, including name, tempName, type, size and error.

In particular you should use the function [getInstancesByName](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile#getInstancesByName-detail) that returns an array of instances starting with specified array name.

```
$temp = CUploadedFile::getInstanceByName("image");  // $_FILES['image']
```

and with this you can access to the file data:

```
$temp->name; // Name of the file
$temp->type; // Type of the file 
$temp->size; // Size of the file
// etc etc..
$temp->saveAs("/your/path/" . $tmp_image . $temp->type); // Save your file
```

for final you can check if the file was saved and execute your query:

```
if($temp->saveAs("/your/path/" . $tmp_image . $temp->type)) {
 // File is saved you can execute the query for save the record in your db
} else {
 // Something went wrong.
}
```

You can also transfer this logic in a model.
  [check this link for more infos](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/95/saving-files-to-a-blob-field-in-the-database/)

Hope this will help you.